# node multer AWS single file multiple upload

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, openshift, multer

Issue trying to upload images Openshift node/express/multer to AWS. The console tells me that there are multiple uploads of the same image and the resulting file on AWS is truncated and broken. I took all the client side ajax out and am just using a standard form upload. Express 3.2.5. Thanks for any ideas.

The console output:

```
in FileUploadData
in FileUploadData
in s3.put
Successfully uploaded data to myBucket/myKey atest.jpg
in s3.put
Successfully uploaded data to myBucket/myKey atest.jpg
in FileUploadData
in FileUploadData
in s3.put
Successfully uploaded data to myBucket/myKey atest.jpg
in FileUploadData
in s3.put
Successfully uploaded data to myBucket/myKey atest.jpg
in FileUploadData
in no req.files
in s3.put
Successfully uploaded data to myBucket/myKey atest.jpg
in s3.put
Successfully uploaded data to myBucket/myKey atest.jpg
```

This is not consistent but always multiple triggers of FileUploadData.
The node code cut-and-pasted from a stackoverflow thread.

```
app.use(multer({
    limits : { fileSize:100000 },
    rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
        return filename.replace(/\W+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
    },
    onFileUploadData: function (file, data, req, res) {
    // file : { fieldname, originalname, name, encoding, mimetype, path, extension, size, truncated, buffer }
        console.log("in FileUploadData");
        var params = {
            Bucket: 'your20images',
            Key: file.name,
            Body: data,
            ContentType: 'image/jpeg'

        };
        s3.putObject(params, function (perr, pres) {
            console.log("in s3.put");
            if (perr) {
                console.log("Error uploading data: ", perr);
            } else {
                console.log("Successfully uploaded data to myBucket/myKey "+file.name);
            }
        });
    }
}));
```

The client side form

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload" id="upform">
    <input type="file" name="imgupload"><br /><br /><input type="submit">
</form>
```

--------------------- edit ----------------------------

Multiple console logs explained in accepted answer bellow. The tentative solution I've found is send to AWS in onFileUploadComplete. Suspect there's a better way but if anyone gets this far bellow worked for me.

```
onFileUploadComplete: function (file, data, req, res) {
        console.log("complete");
        fs.readFile(data.files.imgupload[0].path, function(err, data){
        if(err) { console.log("image rename error: "+err) }
        var params = {
            Bucket: 'myBucket',
            Key: file.name,
            Body: data,
            ContentType: 'image/jpeg'
        };
        s3.putObject(params, function (err, res) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error uploading data: ", err);
            } else {
                console.log("Successfully uploaded data to myBucket/myKey");
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#onfileuploaddatafile-data-req-res) mentions, `onFileUploadData` is called for each *chunk* of each file. So it could easily be called multiple times for the same file.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. So I'm *guessing* what's happening is the chunks are overwriting each other on AWS. Attempting to put the upload in  onFileUploadComplete but failing so far. Will mark as answered once the upload is functional.